# C:\Users\B e B>upgrade pip 'upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

```
C:\Users\B e B>upgrade pip
'upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: How about `pip upgrade`?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#upgrading-pip

Answer (score -1):

Check two possibilities:

1. You are using a current version of pip while the old version of Python.
   Go to your folder Python>>Python 310(or any other no.)>>Scripts, on the top address bar write cmd and then type pip, press Enter
2. You may have installed Python in two different places